# Get the form factor of a Linux machine

Tags: linux, udev, hal

Is there a "usual" way to detect whether a is a laptop, desktop, tablet, phone, embedded device, server, virtual machine and so on without the use of HAL?

In the past this information could be snagged from `smbios.chassis.type`, but as HAL is now deprecated in most Linux distributions I need to get access to this some other way. I can't see anything obvious in `dmidecode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, the chassis type is the form factor of the device:

```
myserver:/ # dmidecode -s "chassis-type"
 Rack Mount Chassis
```

The different types of enclosure are listed in the CIM_Chassis table of the [SMBIOS Specification[.pdf]](http://dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.8.0.pdf)

Comment: Highly dependent on whether the manufacturer actually filled out the DMI structures in a reasonable way, which is unfortunately a very large assumption in some cases, but it's still probably about the best that can be done...